# How do I insert Java variables into a MySQL query?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to create a register system for my MySQL database. I have a Java form that I created, in which the user inserts a username, password, and their email. I take that infromation and store it in a variable accordingly. The MySQL connection code works, and it does insert a new row, but the information is blank on the MySQL page. Am I doing someting wrong?

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
private JPasswordField passwordField;

private static Connection con;
private static PreparedStatement st;
private static int rs;

String username;
String password;
String email;
private JTextField textField_1;

String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO `users`" + "(username, password, email) VALUES" + "(?,?,?)";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Main frame = new Main();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Main() {
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("Barrage : Login / Register");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 350, 200);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Username: ");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(60, 25, 68, 20);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password: ");
    lblPassword.setBounds(60, 59, 68, 20);
    contentPane.add(lblPassword);

    textField = new JTextField();
    username = textField.getText();
    textField.setBounds(138, 22, 120, 26);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    passwordField = new JPasswordField();
    password = passwordField.getText();
    passwordField.setBounds(138, 56, 120, 26);
    contentPane.add(passwordField);

    JButton btnRegister = new JButton("Register");
    btnRegister.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/barrage", "root", "");
                st = con.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
                st.setString(1, username);
                st.setString(2, password);
                st.setString(3, email);
                st.executeUpdate();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
    btnRegister.setBounds(119, 138, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnRegister);

    JLabel lblEmail = new JLabel("E-mail: ");
    lblEmail.setBounds(60, 96, 68, 20);
    contentPane.add(lblEmail);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    email = textField_1.getText();
    textField_1.setBounds(138, 93, 120, 26);
    contentPane.add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);
}
```

}

Comment: See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). It leads to `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't do it this way.  This is a security vulnerability called a [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Instead use a `PreparedStatement` with variable binding (eg: `?`).  [Here is a tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

As for why it's blank in the database (which is what I think you're saying), you're going to have to prove that the value of those variables are not blank with traditional debugging.  IMO, if your tables were set up with the correct constraints (eg: `not null`) it wouldn't even let you insert in that invalid state in the first place.

Comment: I think it is better to use named parameters... Just sayin'

Comment: An upvote for the right approach, but I think the user is not getting the values in varables.

Comment: I am sincerely sorry, but I do not understand what you said. Would you mind to rephrase? Thank you! :D

Comment: @romofan23 ok but what didn't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand PreparedStatement. I have read the tutorial you provided, but I was much too confusing.

Comment: @romofan23 What confused you about it?  I can't write my own tutorial from scratch, but I can help you with specific questions.

Comment: try{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/barrage", "root", "");
     st = con.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
     st.setString(1, username);
     st.setString(2, password);
     st.setString(3, email);
     st.executeUpdate();
    } catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

Comment: I edited the post. Does this help at all? BTW, I would just like to say thank you. Not many people would help as much as you have. God Bless you.

Comment: There are no errors, it's just that the row inserted is still empty

Comment: @romofan23 You are trying to get the user info out side of `ActionListner`. Try to get them inside `actionPerformed` method like `textfieldName.getText()`. I think this will make it work. When you are getting those `textfields`values by that time they were `blank or empty` inserting same into Database.